# Exportar archivo ts en angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de usar un archivo genérico de funciones en angular pero obtengo el error:

error TS2305: Module '"../../../assets/js/funciones"' has no exported member 'funciones'.

El archivo que deseo exportar se llama funciones.ts

```
    export function horaValidador(control: string) {...
```

El componente en el que deseo importarlo:

```
    import  { funciones }  from '../../../assets/js/funciones';
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tienes que importar es el nombre de la función o la clase.

En tu caso:

```
    import  { horaValidador }  from '../../../assets/js/funciones';
```

Comment: Gracias mil. Por la premura y la sencillez en la respuesta